# PHP: Is it better to close SoapClient connection?

Tags: php, soap, soap-client, helper

I created the following helper function:

```
function mainSoap(){
    return new SoapClient('https://soap.url',[
        'stream_context' => stream_context_create([
            'ssl' => [
                'verify_peer' => false,
                'verify_peer_name' => false,
                'allow_self_signed' => true
            ]
        ]);
    ]);
}
```

and I'm using it like `$result=mainSoap()->GetSometing($parameters);`

**Everything works fine**, but in terms of performance, I would like to know if is better to close the soap connection or not.

> **UPDATE**

I created another function in order to close the connection after getting the response, but I still could't find a close method for SoapClient.

```
function mainSoap(string $call=null, array $vars=[]){
    $url="https://soap.url";
    $wsdl=new SoapClient($url,[
        'trace' => false,
        'keep_alive' => false,
        'stream_context' => stream_context_create([
            'ssl' => [
                'verify_peer' => false,
                'verify_peer_name' => false,
                'allow_self_signed' => true
            ]
        ]),
        'compression'   => SOAP_COMPRESSION_ACCEPT | SOAP_COMPRESSION_GZIP | SOAP_COMPRESSION_DEFLATE
    ]);
    $response=$wsdl->__soapCall($call,$vars);
    //Looking for something like $wsdl->close();
    return $response;
}
```

and I'm using it like `$result=mainSoap('GetSometing',[$parameters]);`

Comment: It will get closed when the script terminates, but if you are not going to use it again, then go ahead and close it. If you intend to reuse it, keep it around as making new connetions is comparatively slow

Comment: Thanks @RiggsFolly I was thinking about that too. But I still couldn't find the `close` method for SoapClient.

Comment: That in itself may help you to an answer. But as its an object just setting it to NULL will release the memory, of course it wont get reused until the garbage collector gets activated

Comment: mmm.. after your suggestion, I think that is better to change the function in order to return the result itself and close the connection. But only if I understand how to close it :D

Comment: @RiggsFolly I've changed my function, in order to close the soapClient after the response, but still could't find a close/destroy method for it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [`SoapClient`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php) follows the normal HTTP Request life cycle,

That is to say, your [`SoapClient`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php) **does not maintain a constant connection to the server**, it will only connect out and receive data when called, similarly to how your browser does not maintain a connection to a server once a request completes, as the request is terminated, unless you set `keep_alive` to true.

So, in short, you can't "close" a [`SoapClient`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php) because there's nothing to close after you've called it, it's already closed the connection.

Relevant Links:

- [Wikipedia article on Http (Persistent Connections Section)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Persistent_connections)
- [MDN Documentation on `Keep-Alive` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Keep-Alive)

Comment: I think as today this is not true, at least in php8.1: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=81029